# Resource Leak never closed, after using close() also same error is displaying

Tags: java, arrays

```
import java.util.*;
class smallestelement{
    public static void main(String k[]){
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the size of array");
        int i,a=input.nextInt(),arr[]=new int[a];
        for(i=0;i<a;i++)
            arr[i]=input.nextInt();
        input.close();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
        Arrays.sort(arr,0,a);
        System.out.println(arr[0]);
    }
    
}`
```

After Using input.close() Resource needs to be close But its not working

Comment: What does "not working" mean exactly?

Comment: You don't need to close a Scanner reading from System.in, so you can ignore the warning.

Comment: What "error", at best this is a warning from some static analyzer (though, I admit, some can be configured to raise it as an error).